# What's causing Postgres to freeze?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm using Amazon RDS to run my Postgres database, v9.3.3.

Recently, I had 2 instances where updating the schema caused the database to stop responding and I had to restart it in order to put the site back to normal.

During the freeze, CPU Utilization levels were low (< 15%), Read/Write IOPS did not spike. The only metric that spiked was the DB Connections, which I suppose are all the queries coming in from the web servers.

The first time was to create a new table. The second time was just to add a numeric column into a table with about 10,000 rows of data.

What could be causing these freezes?

Comment: Creating a table shouldn't be able to cause anything much. Adding a column could get stuck on a lock if the table couldn't be exclusively locked, though. Next time, take a snapshot of `select * from pg_stat_activity sa inner join pg_locks l on sa.pid = l.pid`, preferably with `\copy (SELECT ...) TO 'locks_activity_snapshot.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV HEADER)`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to run queries because when it happens, the database server stops responding to anything.

Comment: Sounds like an issue to raise with Amazon support then. They're the only ones with access to debug it. You can't attach `gdb` like usual, because you don't have access to the host.